# Math.random value keeps being chosen?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Ok so basically, for some reason, the first array value of "a0" keeps on being chosen in the for loop math.random section. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it? (P.S., you don't have to read every single String array value)

```
   public class Battleship extends JPanel
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[][] pos = new String[10][10];

        ...
        //we initialize pos here
        ...

        int horcol = 0; 
        boolean[][] tof = new boolean[10][10];
        boolean taken = false;
        int vertcol = 0;
        for(int k=0; k<=9;k++)
        {
            for(int l=0;l<=9;l++)
            {
                if(taken == false)
                {
                int random = (int)Math.random()*15;
                if(random == 1 || random == 2)
                tof[k][l] = true;
                taken = true;
                vertcol = k; 
                horcol = l;
                }
                else
                {
                    tof[k][l] = false;
                }
            }
        }

       }
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I can definitely try.

Comment: Now [edit] it again and reduce it even more, to the *absolute minimum* number of lines that reproduce the problem. See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). While you're editing, change the question title to something that describes the problem or question. *I need help debugging this?* has absolutely no information, and it will be meaningless to future readers who are searching for help with their problem and see it in a search result.

Comment: That is honestly the absolute bare bone minimum because I have no idea where the error is occurring.

Comment: Could you please at least mention which programming language this is.

Comment: You have the statement if(random == 1 || random == 2) but no braces after it. What statements do you expect to be executed if that condition is true? Currently only tof[k][l] = true; will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is remarkably simple.

The issue is with your parenthasis!

Currently you have this:

```
int x = (int)Math.random()*15;
```

So the computer will first do `Math.random()`, which will return a float between 0 and 1 (something ike 0.648294), then make that into an `int`, which will always be 0 because that truncates the number, then multiply by 15, which is still 0.

You need to add parenthesis around the `Math.random()*15` part, like this:

```
int x = (int)(Math.random()*15);
```

That will first multiply the random value by 15, and THEN convert it to an int (and truncate in the process).